# What types of attacks and actions *must* target an enemy with taunt?

Tags: hearthstone

I know that hero and minion direct attacks must target an enemy with taunt, if one exists, but what about other actions:

- Spells that target someone for damage?
- Battlecry attacks?
- Hero powers that target someone?

Comment: Just curious - any color on the downvote? No argument, and feel free to stay anonymous - just genuinely interested in doing better next time I have a dumb hearthstone question. :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to all of these is NO.  Unless the battlecry is one that only targets minions with taunt ([Black Knight](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/The_Black_Knight)) none of these must target a taunt creature.

From the [wiki](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Taunt#Cards_with_Taunt): "...Taunt only affects melee combat - spells and ranged attacks are not affected by Taunt." Keep in mind that the Hunter bow cards: [Eaglehorn Bow](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Eaglehorn_Bow) and [Gladiator's Longbow](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Gladiator%27s_Longbow) do not count as ranged attacks in any way.

Comment: There are no ranged attacks at all, are there? Ranged might be an upcoming keyword ability that ignores Taunt...

Comment: Correct.  I don't know why the wiki chose to use that word.  I probably should've edited the wiki myself to remove it.

Comment: I know it's a grey area whether or not the answer already contains this, but an attacker under the influence of a Misdirection does not listen to Taunt rules, even though it's technically performing a melee attack.